# AssertJ assert on Exception covered another Exception

Tags: exception, assertj, throwable

I'm a beginner of AssertJ. I encountered some issue when I use AssertJ to do Unit Testing.

- **JAVA: version 8**
- **AssertJ: 3.11.1**

I have a source code as below, to capture an exception and throw another exception.

```
try {
    Integer.valueOf(valueA);
} catch(Exception e) {
    throw new XXXException("value is not valid", e);
}
```

My test case as below failed, and I was told wrong exception assert, it's a bit confusing.

```
Throwable thrown = catchThrowable(() -> {
    contract.init(ctx, "A", "100A", "B", "200");
});
assertThat(thrown).isInstanceOf(XXXException.class);
```

The error message as below, it seems like the original exception was captured by AssertJ. Anyone can help? Is it a bug or my mistake of AssertJ API usage? Many Thanks.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting:
  <java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String>
to be an instance of:
  <xxxx.XXXException>
but was:
  <"java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt to reproduce the issue, the test passes as expected:

```java
  @Test
  public void test() {
    Throwable thrown = catchThrowable(() -> f());
    assertThat(thrown).isInstanceOf(RuntimeException.class);
  }

  private void f() {
    try {
      Integer.valueOf("100A");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("value is not valid", e);
    }
  }
```

Can you show us what `contract.init` is doing?

Another possibility would be in the stack trace, if it contains a `%d` somewhere stack trace it might be interpreted by a `String.format` but hard to say without more details.

Comment: It is really not caused by Assertion, just because there was a "%d" for non-number variable to print in catch block. Thank you so much.

    try {
        Integer.valueOf(valueA);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new ChaincodeException(String.format("Account balance is not valid. ('%s': %d)", keyA, valueA), e);
    }